# cakephp 3 - Multiple relationship same table display in index.ctp

Tags: cakephp, relationship

Dears,

I have 2 fields (solicitante and resolvedor) related to the ID field of the users table, how can I display both in the index.ctp?
I use this code below, but I do not know how to differentiate the 2 fields, I put only one field because when I put the two, the information repeats itself

My index.ctp

```
<?= $chamado->has('user') ? $this->Html->link($chamado->user->nome, ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'view', $chamado->user->id]) : '' ?>
```

My Controller

```
public function index()
{

    $this->paginate = [
        'contain' => ['Users']
    ];

    $chamados = $this->paginate($this->Chamados);


    $this->set(compact('chamados'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['chamados']);
}
```

My Model

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->setTable('chamados');
    $this->setDisplayField('id');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');


    $this->belongsTo('Users', [
        'foreignKey' => 'solicitante',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);


}
```

follows the screen image:

[Index.ctp screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DExOC.png)

Answer (score 3):

you can differentiate this way:

```
$this->belongsTo('Solicitantes', [
    'className' => 'Users'
    'foreignKey' => 'solicitante',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);

$this->belongsTo('Resolvedores', [
    'className' => 'Users'
    'foreignKey' => 'resolvedor',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
```

and in your view

```
<?= $chamado->has('solicitante') ? $this->Html->link($chamado->solicitante->nome, ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'view', $chamado->solicitante->id]) : '' ?>

<?= $chamado->has('resolvedor') ? $this->Html->link($chamado->resolvedor->nome, ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'view', $chamado->resolvedor->id]) : '' ?>
```

see the manual

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#belongsto-associations